# I am trying to use the UPDATE SELECT statement on DB2 for IBM i (AS400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Can anyone help me out with an UPDATE SELECT statement on DB2 for i (formerly known as the AS400)?  I am trying to update one table based upon the info. in another table.  Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more detailed in your question.  Do you know how to do this with a different flavor of SQL?

Comment: Please post the code you tried and a description of the columns in the various tables you want to use.  Just click 'edit' to edit the text of your question, thanks!  Also, what version of IBM i are you on?

Comment: It'd be easier to help if we knew what you needed that isn't already included in the [**DB2 for i documentation**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafyexsub4.htm?lang=en) on the subject. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbla A
SET cola = (SELECT colb
             FROM tblb B
            WHERE a.key = b.key
           )
```

The above assumes that either
 - There's a row in tblb for every key in tbla
 - or cola allows NULL values

If the assumption is false, you'll get an error about cola not allowing NULL.

You'll need to either use COALESCE to provide for a default or not attempt to update rows in tbla that don't have a match in tblb.

Lastly, DB2 for i allows Row-Value-Expressions, so the following is also valid:

```
UPDATE tbla A
SET (cola1, cola2) 
         = (SELECT colb1, colb2
             FROM tblb B
            WHERE a.key = b.key
           )
```